# Why would voting Class A Google stock (GOOGL) be selling for less than non-voting Class C stock (GOOG)?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, equity

Currently (2020 October 30), Class A Google stock (GOOGL), which has voting rights, is selling for less than its non-voting Class C stock (GOOG).

This seems backwards.

Why would this ever be the case?

Comment: For reference, the difference (on the 31st) is $5 on a Class A (GOOGL) price of $1616, or about 0.3%. Comparing a handful of matching dates on Nasdaq's charts ([Class A - GOOGL](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/googl) and [Class C - GOOG](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/goog)) shows the A shares slightly under the C price by up to $5. This [Investopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/052615/whats-difference-between-googles-goog-and-googl-stock-tickers.asp) suggests it _should_ be the other way around (C shares cheaper) as OP expects. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] I've no idea if it is the cause (or a contributing factor) but [this InvestorPlace page](https://investorplace.com/2019/02/goog-google-stock-split) mentions possible compensation for holders of non-voting C shares if the price has drifted too far apart "in a year's time". The article is dated Feb 2019, so the year _should_ be up (although COVID may have altered things).

Answer (score 4):

Google buys back class C shares, so as their buy back programme has expanded the value of C shares has risen disproportionality to Class A shares, and will continue to do so as long as they keep buying back only one side of their share class.

Answer (score 2):

Class C's liquidation preference should be above Class A. And as you mentioned, Class C is better protected. If you don't have any voting right to protect yourself, you must have more contractual rights to protect yourself. So security concern is the reason.

This seems indicate that the voting right for each share is less worthy than liquidation preference, at least for this time.

---

With some googling you could find the top results saying that the bankruptcy probability of GOOG is 1.0% or 2.0%, which is significantly lower than the bankruptcy probability of an average US listed company. GOOGL trades about 0.2%-0.3% higher than GOOG, which seems be taking account of the 1.0% bankruptcy risk. Additionally, during the COVID, the bankruptcy risk of many firms have been increased.

Comment: What is this "liquidation preference" you are referring to? It doesn't look like Alphabet Inc. is going to liquidate anytime soon.

Comment: @Flux not at a loss, anyway. If the Class A shareholders decide to liquidate it will be liquidated - but I agree there seems to be little chance of a bankruptcy...

Comment: @Flux According to the latest financial statement, the bankruptcy probability of Alphabet Inc. is 1.0%. Not a big number but not negligible.

Comment: For future reference, the "probability of bankruptcy" of Google can be found here: https://www.macroaxis.com/invest/ratio/GOOG/Probability-Of-Bankruptcy

Answer (score 1):

You are right that normally `GOOGL` is traded slightly higher than `GOOG` thanks to its voting right.

But at the end of the day, the price of anything, Google shares included, is determined by **supply and demand**. At any given moment, `GOOG` can trade higher due to share buyback, short squeeze, large purchase by institutions, etc. (actual events or the anticipation of them).

I do expect, however, `GOOGL` trades higher than `GOOG` after such extraordinary events.